# Icones não ficam na mesma linha

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bom dia. Tenho dois icones dentro de uma table e preciso que eles fiquem na mesma linha. Quando a pagina carrega eles estão alinhados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas, quando navego para uma outra tab e volto para essa tab, os icones estão assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue meu codigo:

```
<td style="width:10%; max-height:20px">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil btn blue-madison" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Editar" style="float:left; position:static">
    <a href="#" class="">
    </a>
 </span>

 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn red exclusao" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Excluir" style="float: right; position: static">
    <a href="#" class="">
    </a>
 </span>
```

O que posso estar fazendo de errado? ou o que estou esquecendo?

Agradecido a quem ajudar.

Comment: Gabriel, evite utilizar CSS dentro do elementl HTML, experimente tirar o style do `glyphicon-trash`

Comment: `glyphicon-trash` parece ser uma classe que traz consigo o próprio icone e talvez outras configurações relativas a ele.. 
Só consigo pensar que um clear:both|left|rght está no estilo destes glypcon(um ou dois)..

Answer (score 1):

Tente não utilizar CSS dentro do elemento HTML.
Para criar botões utilize o elemento `button` do `html5`.

Tente da seguinte maneira:

```
<table>
    <thead>Tabela
       <th>Ações</th>
    </thead>
<tbody>
<td>

<button class="btn btn-warning">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
</button>

<button class="btn btn-success">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
</button>

</td>
</tbody>
</table>
```